# How do I turn off the tag display at the bottom of Visual Studio source windows?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-web-developer

Visual Studio tries to be helpful by showing all the nested tags where the cursor is (the display at the bottom of the code window, next to the "Desgn | Split | Source" options), but I never use it, and it seems to slow things down when I'm just trying to cursor past large blocks of code. Is there any way to turn this feature off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the Tools -> Options -> HTML Designer options doesn't seem to provide a way to turn this off.  You can set the default view, but there is no on/off option.